# Spanish municipality level shapefile and population data

Tags: shapefile, data, population, spain

I'm struggling with the Spanish municipality level.

I need to incorporate population data with the lat/long for each Spanish municipality and below are the details of my current files:

- I cannot find one master CSV having population for each municipality,
  instead I have 52 files having population for municipalities within
  each Spanish province;
- I have the lat/long for each municipality in a separate CSV, and
- The problem is, I need a master CSV with all data in one place and my CSV files don't have an id I can use to map the data.

Comment: This is just a guess (from a QGIS perspective) as I cannot see or test your data but, **assuming both your csv files contain a "municipality" column**, you could add your lat/lon csv file as a _Delimited Text Layer_ where you can select columns from the csv file as `x/y` coordinates. Then do a laborious task of combining the 52 population csv files into one (either copying/pasting or other means). Now from the GIS software, you should be able to do a **JOIN** with the added lat/lon file with the newly merged csv file by selecting the "municipality" column as the _join_ and _target_ field.

Comment: Hey Joseph thanks for the input. The problem here is that I do not have a municipality id that I can use to join. But I do have lat/long columns in both sets and I'm trying to join on the coordinates to no success

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Please provide some more detail...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response; I was using QGIS and yes, I did finally figure the solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know whether you're still after an answer to this problem. Anyway, I'm assuming you're using ESRI GIS. There probably is a similar method in case you're using different software.*

What you're after is the `spatial join` tool. Try this:

1. Load one set of csv-data into your MXD.
2. Right-click the loaded table, hit `display X/Y coordinates` and select the fields with your Lat/Lon
3. Right-click the data again, select data --> export data and save in a GDB or as a shape file.
4. Repeat for your second data set.
5. Navigate to your `Analysis` toolbox and select `spatial join`. Use the data set you want to join your data to as "Target feature". Add a search radius (in case your coordinates aren't identical). Select an output feature class and hit OK.